# Find MenuItem recursively and click it once it found

Tags: javascript, extjs, recursion, menuitem

Hi I am planning to find menu item by traversing recursively all the sub menus .
I have written script but I could not able to debug this console script. I am new to Firebug. Can some one enlighten me on either how to debug this script or a fix to the written script is also welcome.Thanks in advance.

```
var QuickActionFinder = function(component, searchString)
{
      console.log(component.id);
      if(component.hasOwnProperty('text'))
      {
          if(component.text == searchString)
          {
              if(component.hasOwnProperty('textEl'))
          {
                  component.textEl.dom.click();
                  return;   
              }
          }
       }
       if(component.hasOwnProperty('menu'))
       {
          var count = component.menu.items.length;
          for(var i=0;i < count;count++)
          {
             var comp = component.menu.items.itemAt(i);
             QuickActionFinder(comp,searchString)             
          }
      }
      else
      {
         return;
      }
}

var comp = window.frames[2].Ext.getCmp('ext-comp-2515');  QuickActionFinder(comp,'Mobile')
```

Comment: I think you can use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` instead.

Comment: if there are duplicate items in results , I don't want to use either indexing or css locators.